# How to know programmatically if an Index Rebuild/Refresh job is *Running* or *Queued*?

Tags: indexing, scheduler-job

We have this feature which is responsible for **starting Sitecore Index Refresh jobs programmatically** using the static class `Sitecore.Jobs.JobManager` (for different crawler roots).

Now I'd like to create a **method to fetch which is the current state** of a given job.

Do you guys and gals know how that could be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do this.

Firstly, you want to **make sure you start the Refresh/Rebuild properly**.

What I mean by that is that if you want to be able to **identify the right crawler** related to a given Indexing Job, **you will need to tag the Indexing Job with some ID**.

You can do that by adding a **Message** to the job when starting it.

```
Job myRefreshJob = IndexCustodian.Refresh(p_Index, p_PathItem);
myRefreshJob.Status.Messages.Add("Index Refresh IndexName={YOUR_INDEX_NAME} Path={THE_CRAWLER_ROOT_PATH}");
```

By doing that, you will be able to easily identify the given job among all the jobs returned by the `JobManager`.

```
Job foundJob = JobManager.GetJobs().FirstOrDefault(currentJob => currentJob.Status.Messages.Contains("THE_CRAWLER_ROOT_PATH"));
JobState jobState = foundJob.Status.State;
```